# Find rows where column value is contained in input string

Tags: php, mysql

I have prepared a spreadsheet containing several entries, and each row of entry provides two columns of information. One is a product name, and another one is the price of the product. An Example is shown as follows:

```
   Product (Column A)        Price (Column B)
1.      Watch                     $100
2.     Mousepad                    $50
3.     Notebook                  $1000
```

I am trying to create a web-based database with PHP and MYSQL. The basic searching function is that when I enter a sentence in a search box, such as "I have a watch and a notebook", those entries in my database matching some of the words in the sentence would be given (i.e. row 1 "Watch" and row 3 "Notebook"). Does MySQL support this kind of search, and how can I write the query to do so?

Comment: I'm sure you can write a query to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing an SQL query to do that would not be hard. All you need is to write a `WHERE` clause that searches for the column value inside your string. MySQL has a [`LOCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function you can use to search for substrings. In your example, you may have:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE LOCATE(product, 'I have a watch and a notebook.') <> 0;
```

It is important to note, as you'll see in the link, locate returns 0 if the substring is not found.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b9db/1) example.